# ldandroid Error (run ranlib) in Embarcadero

Tags: android, c++, c++builder

I cannot build an application in release mode (C++ Builder 10.2 Tokyo) due to errors with ldandroid. If you know what should I do in such a situation, please let me know.

Command that is generated in IDE:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe 
  --sysroot="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-14\arch-arm" --version-script "c:\program 
  files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\bin\AndroidSymbols.vsr" -shared --no-undefined -z noexecstack -z relro -z now -z muldefs -L.\Android\Release 
  -LDMS_CAMERA -LDMS_SCANNER -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\win64\release" -L"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\osx32\debug" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\iosDevice64\debug" -L"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\iosDevice32\debug" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\android\debug" -L"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\debug" -L"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\release" 
  -LC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\DCP\Android\Release -LC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Dcp\Android 
  -L"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\lib" 
  -L"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\lib" 
  -L"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a" --start-group 
  @".\Android\Release\DMS SCANNERStart.lnk" -lrtlhelper @".\Android\Release\DMS SCANNER.lnk" -lrtle -lrtl -lfmx -lsoaprtl -ldbrtl -lxmlrtl -linet 
  -ldsnap -lsoapmidas -lsoapserver -lbindcomp -lbindengine -lIndyIPClient -lIndyIPCommon -lCustomIPTransport -lIndySystem -lIndyProtocols -lIndyCore 
  -lRESTComponents -lbindcompfmx -lFireDAC -lFireDACSqliteDriver -lFireDACCommonDriver -lFireDACCommon -lfmxFireDAC -lrtlhelper -lsqlib -libtogo 
  -lmidas -lz -lsqlite -lIndyCore -lIndyProtocols -lIndySystem -lcgcrtl -lpcre -ldl -lc -lm -lrtlhelper -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2 -llog -ljnigraphics 
  -lGLESv1_CM -lOpenSLES -lgnustl_static -lLocalizedRTL -lcompiler_rt --end-group  "c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\release\end_android.o"  
  "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\lib\crtend_so.o" -o 
  ".\Android\Release\libDMS SCANNER.so"
```

I tried running this command in command line, checked SDK/NDK paths in Project->Options and they seem to be correct (I have also C++Builder 10 Seattle with installed NDK and SDK, I am using tchem as you can see).

```
[ldandroid Error] C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: rtlhelper: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)

[ldandroid Error] C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\release\start_android.o: in function __linkHelpers:(.text+0x20): error: undefined reference to '__dynamic_delphi_cast'
```

Comment: If you building with runtime libraries, you could configure your project to not build with runtime libraries just to try that out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for your suggestion. It did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Did you get the same `rtlhelper` error though?

Comment: Yes, I got the same errors. I think I'll try solving this problem later on, as I think it may be caused by something in my options/properties. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I moved my project to 10.3 Rio and now it is working well - it was a problem with paths that I couldn't resolve in reasonable time. It took me less time installing newer version of IDE and let it configure everything automatically.